# Integrating burp with selenium to perform active scan on the requests stored in http history

Tags: java, api, selenium-webdriver, automation, burp

I am trying to integrate Burp suite with selenium testng java framework. I have successfully made the requests to pass through proxy server.

Now as the requests are getting stored in the proxy server I want to select those requests and perform active scan on them

**But I am facing null pointer error in the below code lines, which seems like callback object is null
**
this.callbacks.setExtensionName("Active Scan");- in burpSecurity class

burpSecurity.registerExtenderCallbacks(callbacks); - in test class

```
import burp.*;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.awt.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;





public class BurpSecurity implements IBurpExtender, ITab, IHttpListener{

    private IBurpExtenderCallbacks callbacks;
    private List<IHttpRequestResponse> proxyHistoryItems;


    public BurpSecurity(IBurpExtenderCallbacks callbacks) {
        this.callbacks = callbacks;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerExtenderCallbacks(IBurpExtenderCallbacks callbacks) {
        this.callbacks = callbacks;
        this.callbacks.setExtensionName("Active Scan");
        this.proxyHistoryItems = new ArrayList<>();

        this.callbacks.registerHttpListener(this);
        this.callbacks.addSuiteTab(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void processHttpMessage(int toolFlag, boolean messageIsRequest, IHttpRequestResponse messageInfo) {
        if (toolFlag == IBurpExtenderCallbacks.TOOL_PROXY && messageIsRequest == true) {
            this.proxyHistoryItems.add(messageInfo);
        }
    }


    public void performActiveScan() {
        if (proxyHistoryItems == null || proxyHistoryItems.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No requests in proxy history to scan.");

        } else if (callbacks != null) {
            // Log the number of selected items
            System.out.println("Number of selected items: " + proxyHistoryItems.size());
        }

        for (IHttpRequestResponse item : proxyHistoryItems) {
            callbacks.doActiveScan(
                    item.getHttpService().getHost(),
                    item.getHttpService().getPort(),
                    item.getHttpService().getProtocol().equals("https"),
                    item.getRequest()
            );
        }

        System.out.println("Active scanning completed.");
    }

    @Override
    public String getTabCaption() {
        return "BurpSecurity";
    }

    @Override
    public Component getUiComponent() {
        return null;
    }
```

test class

```
private BurpSecurity burpSecurity;
//  private IBurpExtenderCallbacks callbacks;

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setUp(ITestContext context) {

        IBurpExtenderCallbacks callbacks = (IBurpExtenderCallbacks) context.getAttribute("burp_callbacks");
        burpSecurity = new BurpSecurity(callbacks);
        burpSecurity.registerExtenderCallbacks(callbacks);
        callbacks.registerHttpListener(burpSecurity);
    }


@Test
    public void Abc(Map<String, String> data) throws Exception {

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        new LoginPage().........;

        Thread.sleep(15000);
        try {

            System.out.println("testing");
            burpSecurity.performActiveScan();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```